# "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field 0001-01-01T00" when rebuilding index

Tags: solr, indexing

When I rebuild one of my indexes in Sitecore, I get the following error in the Solr log:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field 0001-01-01T00

I don't have a field called `0001-01-01T00`, so I'm not sure what's causing this error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.sitecorecoffee.com/2017/08/solr-queries-errors-related-to-sitecore.html